# Breaker stuck in ON position after faulty dimmer installation

Tags: circuit-breaker

I installed a dimmer, and obviously messed up the connections because when I turned on the corresponding breaker in the main (GE) panel I heard a relatively loud buzzing noise, and then a pop. But here is the strange thing: instead of been in the tripped position (or even in the OFF position), the breaker is stuck in the *ON* position (despite the fact that none of the corresponding fixtures is working). I disconnected the dimmer and none of the cables are touching each other, yet the breaker is still stuck. Any suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion: Call in a professional electrician. At this point it is not at all clear what you caused or has happened.

Comment: Can you post a good quality photo of the panel?

Comment: If the breaker handle will not move to the off position, it's possible that the contacts may have welded shut.  Using a voltmeter, measure the voltage between the breaker terminal and the neutral (or ground) bar in the panel.  If you get a reading of 120V, you're going to want to either shut off the main disconnect, or carefully pull the breaker (if you're comfortable doing that). Then call an Electrician.

Comment: If the breaker welded shut, and your house is not on fire. Some other component in the circuit likely failed, which luckily caused the circuit to open. You're going to have to clear the fault (remove the dimmer), find and repair the failed component (could be a wire, device, connector, etc.), then replace the breaker.

Comment: @Tyson If he can't move the breaker to "off" then the breaker is broken (pun intended).